Can sequents in the sequent calculus contain free variables?
In chapter 14 of Computability and Logic (fifth edition) a proof procedure, specifically a sequent calculus, is introduced. The text states on page 168 that "A sequent $\Gamma\Rightarrow\Delta$ consists of a finite set of sentences $\Gamma$ on the left, the symbol $\Rightarrow$ in the middle, and a finite set of sentences $\Delta$ on the right." It seems to me that this definition is slightly misstated, since the rules of sequent calculus later introduced in the book appear to allow both $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ to contain formulas with free variables in them:

For instance, the rule R6 that from $\Gamma\cup\{A(c)\}\Rightarrow\Delta$ we can deduce $\Gamma\cup\{\exists xA(x)\}\Rightarrow\Delta$ appears to have $c$ as a free variable (which is not in $\Gamma$ or $\Delta$ or $A(x)$).
Am I right in thinking that the sets on either side of $\Rightarrow$ in a sequent should be allowed to contain formulas with free variables? If so, does the sequent calculus introduced in Computability and Logic allow for deductions like $\{c=c\}\Rightarrow\{c=c\}$?

"For instance, the rule R6 ... appears to have  as a free variable"
Much better: it has $c$ as a parameter.

Back to basics. Any formal system for FOL must recognize three different possible semantic roles for expressions that can fill the empty slot(s) in a predicate.

They can be constants (which receive a fixed interpretation, denoting some object in the domain -- used as in $Fn$).
They can be bound variables (best thought of as just parts of complex expressions like $\forall x \ldots\ x \ldots$ -- used as in $\forall xFx$).
They can be parameters or temporary names (the formal analogue of the informal use in "consider an arbitrary  object in the domain, call it $a$ ...").

[For a bit more on why we need some expressions used parametrically, see my answer here.]
How do we mark syntactically the three different roles?
Option (1) familiar from dozens of logic books is to use the same symbols ($x, y, z$) for both uses (2) and (3) -- hence "bound" vs "free" occurrences of "variables", with roles carefully distinguished. Constant-symbols have always a fixed denotation.
Option (2) is also widely in use (see e.g. the formation rules in Richard Jeffrey's classic, Formal Logic: Its Scope and Limits).  This time it is the same symbols which are both used for (1) fixed-denotation names, and for (2) temporary names used parametrically. Variables, the $x$'s and  $y$'s, appear only as part of quantified expressions.
Option (3) -- recommended by the great Gentzen but less commonly adopted -- is to do follow a good Fregean principle, and use three different styles of symbol for the three different roles -- e.g. as it might be $a, b, c$ for parameters, $m, n, o$ for true constants, $x, y, z$ as ingredients of quantifiers.

OK: back to the OP's question. What we have [I think!] in Boolos, Burgess and Jeffrey is a sequent calculus done in a syntax of style (2). Constants can appear parametrically, and wffs with parameters can count as sentences. There is no need for free variables in this system as their role is played by constants which can appear parametrically, without a fixed interpretation.

Thanks for this answer. I'm a bit confused about what the difference between a free variable and a parameter is, though. Also, my understanding is that every sentence has a definite truth value in accordance with Tarski's definition of truth. So, assuming that the language is the language of arithmetic, or something similar, what truth value would formulas like $c=c$, $c\neq c$, or $c=0$ have?

In general: YES. But wrt the specific BBJ's treatment of sequent calculus, they restrict sequents to sentences
See page 106 Syntax: "Thus the more or less traditional $0$0 and $<$ and $'$ [the successor]... we have been writing—and in practice, are going to continue to write—are in principle to be thought of as merely nicknames for $f_0$, and $A^2_0$..."
$0$ is (the only) individual constant symbol in the f-o language of arithmetic. But we have also closed terms, like $0'$ [that is $1$] and so on.
Thus, we have to read $c$ as an individual constant and $s,t$ as closed terms.
Having said that, we have that $\{ c=c \} ⇒ \{ c=c \}$ is a correct sequent, see rule (R0), form which (see Example 14.12, page 173) the authors deduce $\forall x (x=x)$. In the language of arithmetic it will be the sequent $\{ 0=0 \} ⇒ \{ 0=0 \}$.

Does this mean that, in the sequent calculus introduced in the book, we cannot deduce $\forall x(x=x)$ if the language has no constant symbols?

@Joe - you have to check in the text, but if the authors adopt the usual semantics for FOL where the domain must be non empty, wecan always add at least one constant symbol to the language.

Why does $c$ have to be a constant and not a closed term?
